# Overriding defautl search order for find_package

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to avoid cmake find_package to use FindJPEG.cmake from the system, i created a copy of the FindJPEG.cmake and change it a little and put into it a message(STATUS "...") to be able to differenciate it, something like:

```
...
message(STATUS "MY CUSTOM JPEG FIND SCRIPT")
if(NOT JPEG_LIBRARY)
  message(STATUS "MY CUSTOM JPEG FIND SCRIPT >> FIRST TIME FIND LIBRARY")
  find_library(JPEG_LIBRARY_RELEASE NAMES ${jpeg_names})
...
```

then I copied this changed scritp to /my/custom/module/path and then i start my cmake configuration with:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/my/custom/module/path;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}
```

If in my CMakeLists.txt I only call the find_package(JPEG) everything is ok (the custom message is displayed)
But then I add Jasper dependency in my CMakeLists.txt, that also depends on JPEG. So I only need to do a find_package(Jasper) the JPEG dependency will be loaded by jasper.

The problem with the last one is that my FindJPEG.cmake changed script now is not called and I assume that is because the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH search order first starts on the current directory... and do not follow the order specify by my cmake command line.

Can we change this behaviour, or if i'm interpreting this wrong can someone explain better why this is happening?

Thanks
Nuno

Answer (score 2):

If you are shipping with your own custom module path, use:

```
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake)
```

At the beginning of your project, that's the usual pattern, wiuth `CMake` the fodler where your new `cmake` files are located.

Then you may want to also have a look at some variables like [CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/variable/CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH.html) that may be enough to change the search path without rewriting a new `FindJPEG.cmake`.

Comment: nop none override the behaviour that i describe, and i already pass the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH on the command line, because this is not shipped with the library

Comment: If your jpeg library has a different name, then perhaps better to use something differnet than `FindJPEG`.

Answer (score 1):

; so you must use quote to escape -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH="....."

Comment: it's the same...i want to eliminate the search on system paths, only the ones in the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH